# Failed to create Vulkan instance - Windows 10 - VS 2019

Tags: xamarin.android, android-emulator, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I am unable to run Android emulator with Q 10.0 OS. Below are logs I am getting:

```
[2021-01-15 17:21:21.8] 
WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=my_device'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported
[2021-01-15 17:21:21.8] 
WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=5f323b97-8e78-44d1-9682-8c0db057f863'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported
[2021-01-15 17:21:22.6] 
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
[2021-01-15 17:21:22.7] 
added library vulkan-1.dll
[2021-01-15 17:21:22.7] 
emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:537: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.2] 
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.2] 
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.2] 
dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.2] 
dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.2] 
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.2] 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.2] 
dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.2] 
dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.2] 
audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.3] 
emulator: WARNING: System.cpp:1199: Ignoring invalid parameter detected in function: 0000000000000000 file: 0000000000000000, line: 0, expression: 0000000000000000
[2021-01-15 17:21:23.3] 
emulator: WARNING: System.cpp:1199: Ignoring invalid parameter detected in function: 0000000000000000 file: 0000000000000000, line: 0, expression: 0000000000000000
[2021-01-15 17:21:26.4]
```

Tried changing hw.gpu.mode to swiftshader, did not help. API 29 is installed. Does anyone know how to fix it, it works fine on emulator with API 28 (Pie 9.0).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it work, even though HAMX was installed, I had to run **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe** manually to install latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue on the Android TV emulator complaining:

```
Emulator: Android TV (720p) API 30 - Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
Emulator: Android TV (720p) API 30 - Failed to create Vulkan instance.
```

I fixed this by using an x86 image running Tiramisu, API 33 Android 13.0 (Google TV) which got rid of the complaints and works fine now without crashing.

In you're using a mobile emulator, maybe try a newer image running similar API level or above.